# No visible @interface for custom constructor

Tags: ios, objective-c, constructor, interface, header

I was trying to write a custom initializer that looks something like this:

```
 - (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) title withDescription:(NSString *) desc {
    self = [super initWithTitle: title withDescription: desc];
    if (self) {
        self.title = title;
        description = desc;
        duration = 0.0;
        priority = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

But for some reason if I use [super initWithTitle: title withDescription: desc], it tells me that there is no visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares my selector, despite me defining the constructor in the .h file already.

I could just use [super init], but I just wanted to know what I did wrong for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
self = [super initWithTitle: title withDescription: desc];
```

initialize an object by calling its super constructor. However, if super class doesn't contain such a constructor which you are going to call, error message will be shown.

Replace your call with `[super init]`, then `Command` + `Click` on `init` to open `NSObject.h`, you will see only `init` is supported.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. So if I wanted to init my class with the custom initWithTitle:withDescription: would I do [self initWithTitle:withDescription]?

Comment: No, that is not correct if `initWithTitle:withDescription:` is your class constructor. `self` is `nil` before the constructor is invoke, so making a call such as `[self initWithTitle:withDescription:]` will give you compiling error. The correct approach is to call constructor of the `super` class.

Comment: Oh ok. I think I understand now. Thank you for your replies!

Comment: You're welcome. However, please don't forget to add check mark to the answer if it helps resolve your problem. This will help people who's facing the same situation in the future.